# Пунктуация в "закричал как..."

Tags: пунктуация

К примеру: Закричал как девка.

Comment: Ответы на вопросы можно получать быстрее, если пользоваться окном Поиска по сайту.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая может либо ставиться, либо не ставиться. В первом случае сочетание с союзом “как“ принимает значение обстоятельства, а во втором — становится сравнительным оборотом. Такое обособление полностью зависит от характера сказуемого и полноты смысла, который оно несёт. Так, например, Ваше сочетание “закричал как девка“ может быть оценено двумя способами:

1. “Закричал“ полностью передаёт смысл главного предложения. В этом случае акцент делается на том, что человек **закричал**, что характерно для женского пола. Часть с союзом “как“ является придаточным предложением со значением сравнения.
2. “Закричал“ не полностью передаёт смысл и нуждается в обстоятельстве образа действия, раскрывающего, как человек закричал. Здесь “как девка“ — обстоятельство образа действия, относящееся к глаголу “закричал“.

За подробной информацией насчёт обособления конструкций с союзом “как“ обратитесь на портал “Грамота.ру“ по следующей ссылке:

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

*P.s*: люди, может пора прекратить создавать вопросы, ответы на которые уже давно выложены в Интернете? А то мне скоро, боюсь, предъявят обвинение в рекламе “Грамоты“.